# Replacing a Self encrypting Hard Drive in an IBM xseries server raid

Tags: hardware-raid, raid5, disk-encryption, ibm-xseries, drive-failure

I have a failed drive in a RAID 5 array in an IBM x3650, Machine Type 7945.

The RAID is composed entirely of original IBM SED SAS drives, 300GB ea.

Unfortunately I am the purchasing Tech, not the one who goes to the server (just started this week) so there is an absence of information, however the information I have should be sufficient.

I can't find an exact replacement for the drives, nor the recommended replacement from IBM. (44W2265 and 90Y8877 respectivly)

Will another Self Encrypting Hard drive with similar or greater capacity work to rebuild the raid array?

For instance, am I able to replace the drive with a Hitachi UltraStar C10K900 or a SeaGate ST9500620SS?

Answer (score 2):

Call your IBM reseller. They can get it. (as Newegg/amazon still have it in stock)

A tip for IBM, HMM. Google 7945 HMM, and open first link.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systemx/documentation/topic/com.ibm.sysx.7945.doc/PDF_4255_7945_7949_PDSG.pdf

Page 387, send that to the reseller

[image]

Comment: A good suggestion. 

However, we ran into an issue where 2 suppliers gave us fraudulent inventory information (they didn't have them, but they printed a shipping label anyway).
The only items on this list that are Self encrypting are the 44w2265 and the 44w2295. One of them is not available (according to the supplier who is listed on Amazon and Newegg) and the other is too small to be used in this raid.

Comment: Check there to get a quote, to use another channel, http://www-01.ibm.com/software/genservers/commerce/storefronts/. I did a chat with a rep, and it seem still available from them he told me